# Inserting form data into mysql table (safely)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Here is the edited code? I still receive a 404 error and nothing is sent to the database table. I see dbhh.php (which is the following file) after the url on the 404 page after the form is submitted

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_input(first_name1, last_name1, email1) 
    VALUES (:first_name1, :last_name1, :email1)");

    // insert a row

    $stmt->execute([
    ':first_name1' => $_POST["first_name1"],
    ':last_name1'  => $_POST["last_name1"],
    ':email1'      => $_POST["email1"]
]);

        echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the POST variable after you prepare the query. First, make sure that the POST values get assigned to variables.

```
// insert a row
$first_name1 = $_POST["first_name1"];
$last_name1 = $_POST["last_name1"];
$email1 = $_POST["email1"];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_input(first_name1, last_name1, email1) 
VALUES (:first_name1, :last_name1, :email1)");
$stmt->bindParam(':first_name1', $first_name1);
$stmt->bindParam(':last_name1', $last_name1);
$stmt->bindParam(':email1', $email1);
$stmt->execute();
```

Notice the difference. I put the POST one before the query. When the `bindParam` get executed, it can get the values.

Comment: is there a reason not to use `$stmt->bindParam(':first_name1', $_POST["first_name1"]);` etc?

Comment: that's a great idea. it is more efficient. you may post your own answer.

Comment: No @IdontDownVote, people just like to make things "more readable". YMMV

Comment: seems like a very common approach, but objectively unnecessary, but i want to see if i was  missing something on that.

Answer (score 0):

What [@david said](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52547799/edit). Albeit a more compact approach is just skipping the manual binding, and passing params per [`PDO::execute`](http://php.net/PDOstatement.execute) right away:

```
$stmt->execute([
    ':first_name1' => $_POST["first_name1"],
    ':last_name1'  => $_POST["last_name1"],
    ':email1'      => $_POST["email1"]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I edited the code to the following and I am still receiving a 404 error which I can see dbhh.php at the end of the URL which brings the 404 error after the form is submitted

Comment: 404 is not a PHP error, not sufficient to diagnose anything (access/rewrite logs + webdir struct), and an entirely different question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope it will help you.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user_input (first_name1, last_name1,email1) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST['first_name1'], $_POST['last_name1'],$_POST['email1']);
$stmt->execute();
echo "New records created successfully";
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```